# scrapy : The term 'scrapy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet?

Tags: python, powershell, scrapy

I am looking for a python script that searchs for a **(specific word)** in the entire Web page. So after I look around youtube I found youtubers saying "Scrapy is better then bs4".

So I tried with Visual studio / Pycharm but I got this error :

```js
File D:\ScrapyProject\Scripts\activate.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file D:\ScrapyProject\Scripts\activate.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on    
the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
scrapy : The term 'scrapy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was    
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ scrapy
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (scrapy:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

All say the power shell must be updated (**I have updated to latest version 7.2.5**)

```
set-executionpolicy unrestricted
```

and some says I most set it like

```
set-executionpolicy allow all
```

but not solving the issue?

So could anyone help with how to solve this error?

Also, will scrapy help me to find specific phrase in an entire Web page ?

Comment: you need to run those commands from a powershell terminal with administrator priveleges

Comment: @Alexander i did that and the smae error i got, as well please could you tell me if i can search on exact text on the page using scrapy?

Comment: yes you can.  You can do that using requests and regex too.

Comment: you also need to restart the terminal once you have executed those commands

Comment: @Alexander thank you for your help, do you have any youtube video do the trick? thanks a lot

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

Execute below in a admin shell, the command will set all possible policys to unrestricted. 
 The command will fail on MachinePolicy, UserPolicy this will be normally set via GPO/Registry. 
 Reg keys can be found here HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell
or in gpedit.msc 
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows PowerShell

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List | ForEach-Object { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope $_.Scope -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted };
```